# AWS: Is there a way to delete every artifact using string matching?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to remove a lot of created resources in AWS. Buckets, Lambdas, cloudformation, and more. I know everything I need to delete will start with "ABC". Is there a way to just delete everything from the AWS CLI that starts with "ABC"? or even delete resource types that start with the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is not a single command for all of these. You would have to create a **custom script or program**, e.g. in python, to list all your resources in questions, filter them out by name, and delete what is needed.

Comment: Disappointing to hear but I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it won't handle everything (CloudFormation isn't on their list, unfortunately), [cloud-nuke](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke) can delete artifacts based on regex strings (both inclusive and exclusive) so this might be a good tool for most cases.